# how to get all nodes with same value of certain attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<Darstellung>
  <Info Art="Kurztext" Wert="Top Qualität in verschiedenen modischen Farben!" Rang="1"/>
  <Info Art="Bild" Wert="bildname_1.jpg" Rang="1"/>
  <Info Art="Bild" Wert="bildname_2.jpg" Rang="2"/>
  <Info Art="Veredelungsart" Wert="Tampondruck" Rang="1"/>
</Darstellung>
```

And I want to take all the nodes, that have value "Bild" of the attribute `Art`. Actually I want to retrieve the value, which is in attribute `Wert`, but for that I first need to select all the nodes with value "Bild" of `Art`.

This is the XPath I have now:

```
Darstellung/Info[@Art='Bild']/@Wert
```

but it returns me only the first node.

Comment: This XPath is correct and should do what you want. However, the XML above is invalid -- that might be part of the problem.

Comment: @Jon - yep, I just forgot to put `/` at the last node, when I was typing the code here in my question. Otherwise in my XML file it's correct.

Comment: @Syspect Your first `Info` element is also invalid because it isn't closed.

Comment: Yep, the problem is only here in the post. Sorry for that.
Anyway, the problem was that the function that treats my XPath returns an array of arrays and I had to go deep in order to get my desired value. The XPath was correct at all times. So - problem solved. :)